# Insert HTML of Draggable div into textarea's specific position in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to insert draggable div's html into textarea's specific position.

There are some draggable divs , I want to drag the div into a textarea, when I release the left mouse button the div html() will be automatically appended into the textarea's cursor position.

Is there any solution?

My code

```
$('#datasource-column-container').find('ul > li').each(function (i, element) {

    $(element).draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        helper: "clone",
        connectToSortable: '#template-htmlarea',
        zIndex: 999,
        stop: function () {
            // alert($(element).html());
            // $('#template-htmlarea').html($(element).html());
            $('#template-htmlarea').insertAtCaret($(element).html());
        }
    });

    //$(element).sortable();
});

$.fn.extend({
    insertAtCaret: function (myValue) {
        if (document.selection) {
            this.focus();
            sel = document.selection.createRange();
            sel.text = myValue;
            this.focus();
        } else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
            var startPos = this.selectionStart;
            var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
            var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
            this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos) + myValue + this.value.substring(endPos, this.value.length);
            this.focus();
            this.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
            this.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
            this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
        } else {
            this.value += myValue;
            this.focus();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Show us what you have done till now?

Comment: Hello RahulB I posted my code